# Android Studio how do I create an image that has no square bounds around it?

Tags: android, android-studio, bitmap, onclick, imageview

Unexpectedly I was unable to find a way in the internet on how to create an image object that has no square bounds around it, so that onClick event should only fire up when a user click inside the image.

[image: onClick event should not fire up when a user click at this point outside the image]

[image: onClick event should only fire up when a user click at a point inside the image]

All ways and methods are greatly welcomed. Thank you.

Comment: even if you could get an image to not have a square border, the imageview that you put it in will still be square

Comment: images are rectangles by definition.

Comment: Well for an example, in html, we can us svg object to create the image so that the object's shape is the same as the image, no square bounds around it, now I have tried using svg in android studio and there is still the invisible square bounds, where the click event will fire up if you click outside the image

Comment: you cannot do what you want in android, everything is rectangular

Comment: Yes, I am starting to think it is impossible to  do, thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you used as an ImageView ,you can set : **background="@null"**,wish this can help you.

Comment: nah, doesn't work, the onClick event still fired up when its clicked outside the image..

Comment: Sorry for my poor English, I misunderstood you. This can be solved by defining a View's subclass and override onClickEvent() method . when image clicked,get  color values of points  those had been touched,if one color value is green,responsed the event.else if all were transparent，stop it and return.

Comment: Thank you, that seems like it will work, could you guide me on the method to get the color values of the points touched ? is it the getSolidColor() method ?

Comment: I post a sample below.

Answer (score 0):

that's a sample from other's blog :

```
 @Override

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    int action = event.getAction();

    if(action != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

        return super.onTouchEvent( event);

    }

    int x = (int)event.getX();

    int y = (int)event.getY();

    if(width == -1 || height == -1) {

        Drawable drawable = ((StateListDrawable)getBackground()).getCurrent();

        bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();

        width = getWidth();

        height = getHeight();

    }

    if(null == bitmap || x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= width || y >= height) {

        return false;

    }

    int pixel = bitmap.getPixel( x, y);

    if(Color.TRANSPARENT == pixel) {

        return false;

    }

    return super.onTouchEvent( event);

}
```

That's the blog: [click here](http://www.cnblogs.com/vanezkw/p/3806360.html)

The blogger realized the function that clicking different parts of chrome icon, deepened color of the part which is clicked,here the event was responsed by judging color.

Good night!

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will try this method.